# Value of property QueueConfigurations must be of type List

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I am trying to write SQS triggers for my S3 bucket. I am running into an error saying "Value of property QueueConfigurations must be of type List." Is there something wrong with my indentation/formatting? Or is it a content error? I recently had to transcribe this from YAML to JSON, and I could really use a second pair of eyes on this issue. Keep in mind that the reason the codeblock below is so indented is because I have some sensitive info I shouldn't post. Thanks in advance!

```
          "NotificationConfiguration" : {
              "QueueConfigurations" : {
                "Id" : "1",
                "Event" : "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
                "Filter" : { 
                  "S3Key" : {
                    "Rules" : {
                      "Name" : "prefix",
                      "Value" : "prod_hvr/cdc/"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "Queue" : "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:958262988361:interstate-cdc_feeder_prod_hvr_dev"
              },   
              "QueueConfigurations" : {
                "Id" : "2",
                "Event" : "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
                "Filter" : { 
                  "S3Key" : {
                    "Rules" : {
                      "Name" : "prefix",
                      "Value" : "prod_hvr/latency/"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "Queue" : "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:958262988361:interstate-latency_hvr_dev"
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like below. And as per this [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig-queueconfig.html), "Id" is not a valid attribute.

```
{
  "NotificationConfiguration": {
    "QueueConfigurations": [
      {
        "Event": "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
        "Filter": {
          "S3Key": {
            "Rules": {
              "Name": "prefix",
              "Value": "prod_hvr/cdc/"
            }
          }
        },
        "Queue": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:958262988361:interstate-cdc_feeder_prod_hvr_dev"
      },
      {
        "Event": "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
        "Filter": {
          "S3Key": {
            "Rules": {
              "Name": "prefix",
              "Value": "prod_hvr/latency/"
            }
          }
        },
        "Queue": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:958262988361:interstate-latency_hvr_dev"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @sayboras! This really helped!